# Is there anyway I can have PowerShell write out the local security policy and the local audit policy?

Tags: powershell

I am writing a PowerShell script and i want it to print out what the local security policy (Password History, Password Complexity, Session lock etc) as well as the local audit policy's to a text file.

For Local Security Policy I have tried:

```
secedit.exe /export /areas SECURITYPOLICY /cfg |
    Out-File C:\Users\admin\Desktop\results2.txt -Append
```

I haven't tried anything for local audit policies, I've been stuck on the local security policy

Comment: This might give you some tip, [ServerFault - Command line tool for listing audit policy settings](https://serverfault.com/questions/802570/command-line-tool-for-listing-audit-policy-settings)

Comment: What happened when you tried with the command you've shared? Errors? No output? Partial output? Computer catch fire?

Comment: I didnt get any output from this command